# Calculate Database Field Value and Send to Views as New Field

Tags: views, 8

I have a database field which stores a timestamp. This timestamp is sent to a custom views provider via `hook_views_data()`. This timestamp field is created as a date field to utilize the date format options from views.

```
$data['module']['timestamp'] = [
  'title' => t('Timestamp'),
  'help' => t('Timestamp from module'),
  'field' => [
    'id' => 'date',
  ],
  'sort' => [
    'id' => 'date',
  ],
  'filter' => [
    'id' => 'date',
  ],
];
```

---

In another views field (but with the same DB field), I would like to get the raw field value and run it through something like:

```
if (field_value > (time() - 800))
```

---

This is a custom module and would prefer not to have any more dependencies. Can this be achieved with `hook_views_data()` or `hook_views_pre_render()` or such?

I know there is a contributed module https://www.drupal.org/project/computed_field, but again hoping there is a way in those hooks, or in the view...

The DB table is created with `hook_install()` and the desired timestamp field output after check would be markup. Happy if it is just sent as markup to the views field.

---

I've figured how to access the field values with `hook_views_pre_render()` as such:

```
function hook_views_pre_render(&$view) {
  $result = $view->result;
  foreach ($result as $key => $row) {
    kpr($result[$key]->field_name);
    if ($result[$key]->timestamp > (time() - 800)) {
      // Can I do anything here?
    }
    else {
      //
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, that is not the most important piece of the puzzle. And it is not possible to just add `$data['module']['key']` to my `hook_views_data()` as this requires the unique DB field to exist.

In my use case, I'd be happy if I could rewrite the original timestamp field and append this markup to it.

Comment: If I do `$result[$key]->timestamp = $result[$key]->timestamp . $myAddedData;` inside my `if` statement, it does indeed rewrite the value (though doesn't seem the right way), but I'm hoping I can have this as a field in views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this, it shows how you can create custom fields that you can use within views https://www.webomelette.com/creating-custom-views-field-drupal-8

I've followed this recently and seems to work well

Comment: This has worked well. Having the `public function query()` empty was the trick so that views ignored there is no DB field. Maybe add that to your answer? Just a note, to kpr() in `public function render(ResultRow $values)` I had to `return kpr($values);` to have my kpr() sent to display. This seems like a valid approach to me.